# Nautilus - Open with Sublime - Open in new window

Tags: nautilus

In Nautilus on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, when I choose "open with" and then select "Sublime", the document will always open in any existing instance you have open. If I use the CLI and call `subl --new-window [path to file]` then I get the desired behaviour.

How can I add the `--new-window` argument to the call that nautilus is executing to open with Sublime?

Comment: Easily done editing by sublime's .desktop or thru a nautilus action, But -  The default for sublime is to remember/re-open last session. So in that case if you edit the .desktop or a nautilus action is  used on a file with sublime not open you'll get 2 windows opening - the new one & one reflecting previous session/tabs. So editing the .desktop is out unless you want to disable that feature. If using NA then you'd only use it when sublime is already open. Which do you prefer?

Comment: I have disabled sublime from remembering my previous session/tabs so I just need to update `.desktop`, now just to figure out what exactly that means...

Comment: Great I just had to replace `Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F` with `Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n %F` (see the `-n`) in the file:  `/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop`. If you put up such an answer I will mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is just to edit sublime's .desktop & add the -n option to the Exec= line. This works well when one has disabled sublime's default of remembering the last session.

To do so just run `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop` & add -n to the Exec= line so it looks like -

`Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n %F`

Also to note - on some systems sublime will cause cursor run on when used from the context menu. If that's the case while the .desktop is open to edit scroll down to the `StartupNotify=true` line & make it `StartupNotify=false`. This will prevent cursor run on..

(- for those not used to nano  - after editing go -

ctrl+o

press enter key on keyboard

ctrl+x

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question but a tricky one to answer. I haven't used Sublime myself but problem is similar with Gedit as well. If you prefer you can use *Nautilus actions* to add a context-menu item. Install it through Software center.

If you want to create Nautilus script you will have to use `$@` characters as substitution of environment variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"; do 
    gedit --new-window "$i" & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --name "$i" windowactivate
done
exit 0
```

The -`xdotool` here is to raise windows because they all runs in the background but you can alter the behavior the way you are familiar with, spread them around or just live it alone the way it is.